# C++ Predictable Rand() Output

Tags: c++, random

After noticing that the rand() function produced the same output of 41 each time, I seeded the generator using srand(time(0)). That solved the problem of the recurring output but now it's giving me constantly increasing numbers. (I.E. 245, 248, 250, 253, 255, 256). I can understand that it is increasing because of the influence by the system time but is this normal?

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int number;

    srand(time(0));

    cout << rand() % 1000;

    return 0;

}
```

I am running this repeatedly and not in a loop.
Outputs of multiple trials:
285
295
305
311
325
334
344
354
355

Comment: The numbers `245, 248, 250, 253, 255, 256` cannot be output with the code you have shown since it is modulo 100.

Comment: I was using those numbers as an example of what I am getting but you get the point.

Comment: Don't show us a hypothetical example of what you're getting. Show us what you're getting. And is that the actual code that produced those numbers? Your program prints only one number (and without a newline); are you running it repeatedly, or does your actual program have a loop?

Comment: How many times did you test it? There's about a 1/32 chance that a sequence of 6 random numbers will be monotonically increasing -- not very likely, but quite possibly coincidental.

Comment: I updated the post with the actual outputs. After 9 + trials, the numbers still retained the predictable fashion of +10.

Comment: Don't you know the difference between pseudorandom and random? You should google it, it's mostly on the wikipedia.

Comment: Pure curiosity: Does an extra `rand();` call (right after `srand`) solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

C++ `rand()` from MS uses the simplest random generator [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

This is the code for it:

```
int __cdecl rand (
    void
    )
{
    _ptiddata ptd = _getptd();

    return( ((ptd->_holdrand = ptd->_holdrand * 214013L
        + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff );
}
```

So whenever you seed your function you just set the first value (which obviously increases just by some units from time to time if you run your program fast)

Now if you plug in your math equation of the `rand()` a value `x+a` where `x` is the value with which your function was called last time and `a` is the variation of your time since that call you will notice:
((x+a) * 214013 + 2531011) >> 16 = (x*214013+2531011 + a*214013) >> 16

Since you run your program very fast. Your `a` varies between `0` and `5` sec let's say. Then your `a*214013` has a max value of `1070065` now when you right shift this number by 16 bits you end up with `16` in decimal and this is **approximately** how much your new output differs from your previous one (I say approximately because you can not say that (x*214013+2531011 + a*214013) >> 16 = (x*214013+2531011 >> 16) + (a*214013 >> 16) because of the carries)

Comment: Good catch. Note: based on the link you posted you're talking about the MS implementation, I think you should mention it in your answer. glibc uses way bigger multiplier and all the bits which explain why you don't see this behaviour on those platforms.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thank you for noticing, since I use only their compiler and I am not involved that much in the "compiler topic" I wrongly assumed that this implementation is the same for all C++ compilers.

Comment: Interesting but not really helpful. Better to just tell the OP not to reseed the generator.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker it does answer his question.

Comment: True, that's why I didn't downvote. But the fact that the generator is bad isn't the *cause* of his problem. Even if he were using a much better generator, that generator algorithm isn't really being used at all, only the seeding function.

Answer (score 4):

This bug comes up about once a week here:

If you call `srand()` every time before you call rand(), then you're not getting random numbers at all, you're getting a hash function of the time. Call `srand()` ONCE, AND ONLY ONCE, outside the loop, preferably at the very start of your program, then call `rand()` as many times as needed to get values.

There's no such thing as generating "one random number". If you need random numbers over a series of program invocations, you have no choice but to generate those random numbers outside the program. One way to do that is to read from `/dev/urandom` (on Linux) or use `CryptGenRandom` (on Windows). Another option is to use hardware, or a service like `random.org`.

It doesn't matter how good a generator you have--if you seed every call, you're not getting random numbers, you're getting a hash function of the seed value. If your seed value changes fast enough, and the hash function is very good, that might be good enough--but it's still not using the RNG algorithm at all.

Comment: `outside the loop` Where is the loop? The OP is seeding it only once at the very start of the program.

Comment: The "loop" is running the program multiple times. To seed outside the loop, he has to generate the rands outside the program.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are getting those results, but there are better ways in C++11:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto rnd = std::default_random_engine(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 999);
    std::cout << dis(rnd) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to C++ so that code will take me a bit of time to understand. I'll try it out though. Thanks!

Comment: Not helpful at all. OPs error is obvious: he's re-seeding the generator on every call. You're doing exactly the same thing (altough "call" in your case is running the program. This won't generate random numbers at all, just a hash function of the seed values.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: He said in the comments: `I'm running the program once every 2 seconds` and the code in his example is only calling `rand` once. Also, do you even know what `std::random_device` is? Your comment does not make any sense.

Comment: The C++ standard does not *require* that std::random_device be hardware-based, but it probably will work fine on most implementations. If it were my code, though, I would read /dev/urandom myself just to be sure.

Comment: `I would read /dev/urandom myself just to be sure`, there is no point as `std::random_device` **uses** /dev/urandom by default.

Answer (score 0):

The way `rand` works is you need to follow two rules:

1. you must seed it first (`srand`) and
2. you don't want to seed it before every call to `rand`. You are just to seed it once before your entire sequence.

So to really test it you, your code should look more like this:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    // Output a sequence of 100 random numbers, each less than 1000
    for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )    
        cout << rand() % 1000 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If the program by necessity only outputs one random number each run and the program runs as often as once per second or more, then `time(0)` may not be a suitable seed. Perhaps using `clock_gettime(3)` which will give you something more in the milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the warning but I will only be generating a random number once in the program. The problem here is that when I run it multiple times, the random numbers don't differ by much (especially as the modulus gets smaller).

Comment: @RobertLu OK, how frequently will the program be run? I just tried your case of once each run and didn't have a sequencing issue. But I did notice that if I ran it rather quickly in succession it would repeat a value. If `time()` doesn't provide a suitable seed (it changes once per second) maybe you need a different seed generator.

Comment: @RobertLu: You'll (probably) get the *same* number if you run the program twice within the same second, since `time()` typically has a resolution of 1 second. That doesn't explain the increasing sequence you're seeing, but we need more information about that.

Comment: I'm running the program once every 2 seconds.

Comment: I'd probably try using `clock_gettime` or something like that. `rand` is pseudo random and deterministic.

Comment: Woudln't gettime produce the same increasing output that I'm currently getting?

Comment: @RobertLu It provides a more granular time measure which could be used to create a more varied seed. So I was expecting not. But you should give Jesse Good's answer a go. It looks quite promising.

Comment: I think the point is that `clock_gettime` gives you a nanosecond time portion as well as a time in seconds. You could then combine those two into a single 32-bit number, e.g. by xor (`^`), so that you get a "very fast changing" number, that isn't very predictable.

Comment: There's no such thing as "one random number". If you need a set of random numbers across multiple invocations of a program, you'll have to generate them outside the program. Reading from `/dev/random` or getting numbers from random.org are a couple of ways to do that.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker of course. You took my phrase out of context. I said "one random number each run" implying a sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`rand` is implemented as a linear congruential generator in runtime libraries and this has the form:

```
result = (seed * result + offset) % big_number
```

If we consider `big_number` to be infinity and you run your program at time `t` you get

```
result = t * result + offset
```

If you run the program again after a very short period `alpha` you get

```
result = (t + alpha)* result + offset
```

If the runtime library initializes result with a small value, the displayed result would increment with the small value of `alpha * result`.

Replacing `time()` with a higher resolution counter would greatly improve this. For example on x86, `rdtcs` instruction (often available as a compiler intrinsic) would almost solve the issue.

A better solution is to use a non-linear congruential generator to seed `rand()` like the one suggested by Jesse Good which is also available on non-c++11 compiler through boost library.

When possible, it's better to stick with c++11 random generators rather than c rand.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across the same problem and found that Karoly Horvath's comment on your original question solved the issue, although it is a bit "hacky".  I was seeing a predictable increase in return values, and after sticking another `rand()` immediately after the `srand()`, the problem went away.  I ended up with this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
rand();
int seed = rand();
```

I'd like to figure out **why** this is happening...but in the meantime this works.