# creating a random number between 0 to 1 continuously

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, random

I am trying to model a stock price movement in C++. I need to create a random number between 0 to 1.

But it seems that the random number generator value keeps increasing and is not really random.

The code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double stockPrice = 25;
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    start = clock();

    srand (time(NULL));
    cout << (double) rand() / (double) (RAND_MAX) << endl;
    system("pause");

    while(stockPrice > 18)
    {
        if(stockPrice == 20)
        {
            double probability = (rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
            if(probability <= (1/10))
            {
                stockPrice = stockPrice-1;
            }
            else
            {
                stockPrice = stockPrice +1;
            }
        }
        else if (stockPrice < 20)
        {
            double probability = (rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
            if(probability <= (1/3))
            {
                stockPrice = stockPrice -1;
            }
            else
            {
                stockPrice = stockPrice +1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            double probability = (rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
            if(probability <= (2/3))
            {
                stockPrice = stockPrice -1;
            }
            else
            {
                stockPrice = stockPrice +1;
            }
        }
        cout << stockPrice << endl;
    }

    end = clock();

    double t = (double)(start-end)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << t << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Not sure how to solve this.. Need some guidance...

Comment: "the random number generator value keeps increasing and is not really random." - nope!

Comment: yes. the values created are 0.812, 0.814 and so on.. How to fix this?

Comment: @lakesh if that happens on every re-run of the program, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385541/c-predictable-rand-output/17385746#17385746) is the explanation.

Comment: Since this is c++ why don't you use any of the modern random number generators provided? [random_device](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)

Comment: Have a look at the standard library's [uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Comment: @lakesh could you still add more info regarding *"the values created are 0.812, 0.814 and so on"*

Comment: If not c++11, why not use the [boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/random/) instead of rand(). They should provide a much better distribution of numbers.

Comment: better under what measure?

Comment: "better" as in withstanding better to (statistical) tests when compared to the properties of a "*true*" random generator, see e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Need some guidance...

*guidance 1:*

correct comparisons, you should use

```
double probability = (rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX + 1));
                                               ^
                                        for better scaling
```

because currently in line `if(probability <= (1/10))` you are comparing with 0 because of conversion `1/10` `1/3` and `2/3` to integer

*guidance 2:*

after all you might use generator with better [statistical properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);
    double uniformOn01 = dis(gen);
```

Comment: The random number generator is **not** the problem. The problem is comparing probabilities whose values are between 0 and 1 with fractions like `1/3`; the values of these fractions are always 0.

Comment: I think you should use `rand()/((double)RAND_MAX + 1)` to avoid integer overflow problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(probability <= (1/3))
    {
    stockPrice = stockPrice -1;
    }
else
    {
    stockPrice = stockPrice +1;
    }
```

Since `probabililty` is never negative, this code will **almost always** increment the value of `stockPrice`. The only time it won't is when `probability` is 0. That's because `1/3` is **integer** division, and its value is 0. Change all of these fraction to something like `1.0/3` and things will be much better. And this has **nothing** to do with the quality of the random number generator. Some folks get so exercised when they see `rand` that they don't see anything else.

However, there **is** a flaw in the scaling in the code. Instead of

```
double probability = (rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
```

use

```
double probability = (rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX + 1));
```

As originally written, the value of `probability` will be 1 whenever `rand()` produces the value `RAND_MAX`, and it will produce other values much more often.

Answer (score 0):

In all of your cases where you compare the probability you have integer division, which all result in 0...  instead of `(2/3)` you wanted `(2/(double)3)` or `2/3.0`.

Comment: While this is true, it does not answer the question being asked. xD

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - um, yes, it does answer the question. The way the code is written, it will **almost always** increment the stock price.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think the question is related with the values of the random number itself, not the stock price.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - despite the noise from the anti-`rand` folks, there is no implementation on the planet that does what the question describes. The code itself is wrong, and it will steadily increase the stock price. If there are still problems after that's fixed, it **might** be appropriate to look at the quality of the generator. However, for a simple program like this, `rand` is good enough, and any problems are in the code itself.